# How to receive file contents in a bean method using apache Camel file component?

Tags: java, apache-camel

i am trying to read file using apache camel file component as :

consBean is registered correctly.

ConsumerBean have following method:

```
public void beanRoute(File body){

            System.out.println("Bean method is called -->" +body);
        }
```

My RouteBuilder have following  code :

```
public class KafkaRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:C:\\ccd?fileName=CCD.xml&delay=5000&noop=true.to("bean:consBean?method=beanRoute(${body})");
}
```

My Test Class simply create new RouteBuilder as :

Constructor Code:

```
public CamelTest(){

        this.ctx =new DefaultCamelContext();
        PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry reg = (PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry)ctx.getRegistry();

        ((JndiRegistry)reg.getRegistry()).bind("consBean", new ConsumerBean());
        PropertiesComponent properties=new PropertiesComponent();

        properties.setLocation("com/camel/test/props.properties");
        ctx.addComponent("properties",properties);

    }
```

Main Method Code :

```
ctx.addRoutes(new KafkaRouter());
        ctx.start();
```

code runs successfully but not able to get any output in the bean method (bean method is not called)

Comment: You are aware that the start method on CamelContext is non blocking, so you need to keep your app running: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: so how we should deal with files in camel if they have to wait to fetch data from file and process its contents ? thanks for reminder that was hit rightly. but making Threads sleep is not what is recommended. Is it that files should be handled separately then ?

Comment: Read the documentation on that link, see the links in the bottom and continue reading